# Can't get Wyvern to show YouTube button

Tags: wysiwyg, wyvern

I want to add the YouTube button to Wyvern fields. I enabled it in Wyvern's config.php:

```
    'Styles' => 'no',
    'Syntaxhighlight' => 'no',
    'YouTube' => 'yes',
```

etc...

placed the YouTube plugin in the correct folder
http://ckeditor.com/addon/youtube

and added

```
config.extraPlugins = 'youtube';
```

to CKEditor's config.js.

The button shows up in Wyvern's config screen in EE, but does not show up in the Wyvern fields.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the youtube plugin files in your ckeditor/plugins folder?

Comment: Yes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dn19f9gapedu1fx/wyvernYT.png?dl=0

Comment: I don't know about Wyvern however with Wygwam the thing is the CKEditor config is controlled by the CP actions, it's not the base CKEditor config.js! If Wyvern is at all similar you may find CKEditor configs stashed in the DB or in the Wyvern module. Have you looked for other instances, maybe it's just the `config.extraPlugins = 'youtube';` line getting missed for the config for the specific editor? I remember this from trying to add the ImageMap plugin to CK on Wygwam.

Comment: Also I note there is no icon on the screenshot, this could just be a quirk however from memory (so please excuse me if I'm wrong!) this could indicate this is al old CKEditor2 plugin (structure) and not a CKEditor3 one. I'll try to find a copy of Wyvern, if I can find one I'll give this a crack myself for you as I'm interested myself :) Extending CKEditor, inside Wyvern, inside EE, inside a taco bell :D

Comment: I'm using CKEditor 4.4.6. @BrianLitzinger - any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Ok, so one thing to check is that the plugin is all up to date (go get a copy of just CKEditor and check the plugins against each other). It's likely it will be. Next thing is to go digging for other potentual CKEditor config files. look through the Wyvern Module files, The CKEditor files and the look in Wyverns settings within the DB too. It's likely Wyvern is storing it's configs elsewhere and/or the button has been removed from the toolbar config. If you can post what you find and where I can perhaps push an example (difficult without Wyvern!)

Answer (score 1):

Stop the presses,

I don't see in your question if you followed the documented process over at bold minded here : https://boldminded.com/add-ons/wyvern/documentation (all my quotes below are from this site)

So Step one (which I assume you've done as you can see it in the field list) :

> Adding 3rd Party Plugins (after version 1.2.7)
>
> Place your CKEditor plugin inside the
>   /themes/third_party/wyvern/plugins/ folder. In the ExpressionEngine
>   control panel go to Add-ons » Fieldtypes » Wyvern and select your
>   plugin in the multi-select menu to enable it.

Now, Step 2 all you need to do is add it to the toolbar :

> Adding buttons to the toolbar
>
> By default, Wyvern intentionally comes with a limited set of CKEditor
>   buttons in the Fieldtype settings page. I have chosen to keep the
>   default list to the essentials for simplicity. If a button you need is
>   not found in the Toolbar list, open the
>   system/expressionengine/third_party/wyvern/config.php file. You will
>   see an array which defines the default list, as well as the rest of
>   the available CKEditor buttons, which are commented out. To enable a
>   button, simply remove the code comment prior to that button. Go back
>   to the Add-ons > Fieldtypes > Wyvern page and the button will be
>   available within the Toolbar list.

**Note** This is not CKEditors "config.js" but Wyverns "config.php".

I'm not sure from your question if you have seen this page or anything, but can you try this process and let us know how you get on! I would recommend rolling your changes back and trying this first...

Comment: OK. I've followed these steps carefully. But apparently, changes I make in the buttons array - /system/expressionengine/third_party_wyvern/config.php are not being reflected in Add-ons > Fieldtypes > Wyvern.

Comment: It's the first part that effects `Add-ons -> Fieldtypes -> Wyvern` display, you shouldn't need to add anything to the buttons array to get the plugin to show there (you did put the youtube CKEditor plugin in the _wyvern_ plugin director, not CKEditor, right??). This is why I suggested rolling back first, because of your previous work that could effect this. The second part deals with getting it to show in the toolbar only. Its a shame I don't have a Wyvern licence or I'd try it and supply with an example but I do beleive you cna do each stage seperately to check your works.